# How can I calculate a weekly average in Excel from a certain figure

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a figure which is 2880 in cell A1 lets say it's a monthly salary and in this example there are 31 days in the month.

What I want to work out is what would be the weekly average of this figure. Considering it is just over 4 whole weeks - I can't divide by 4 as that's not accurate but then I can't divide by 5 either for the same reason.

So what I need is a calculation which can give me an exact weekly average - is this it all possible or am I trying to complicate matters?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Do you need an average for just a particular 31 day month or are you looking to more generically solve this for any month?

Comment: `2880/(31/7)`  This is more a math question than a programming one and should probably be asked on a different forum

Comment: Joshua just as 31 day month but Scott has solved the problem

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, much appreciated

Comment: Some people may also do `((2880*12)/365)*7`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula where cell `C2` is the number of the month (March would be 3):

```
=ROUND(C3/(DATE(1,C2+1,1)-DATE(1,C2,1))*7,2)
```

See screenshot of the example:

[image]